# How to delete duplicate rows and keep just one row with multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have duplicate data in a table called `bank_currency` that looks like this:

```
currencyid | bankid
--------------------
8             1
8             1
8             1
16            2
16            2
16            2
14            3
14            3
14            3
```

I have no idea why the data has been duplicated in triplicate, but I need to get rid of all the duplicates and keep only one of each row. So I end up like this:

```
currencyid | bankid
--------------------
8             1
16            2
14            3
```

I cannot `ORDER BY` the `bankid` or `currencyid` to tell postgresql which row to keep, because they are duplicate. Perhaps an order by `ROW_NUMBER` (if thats possible) and just keep the lowest `ROW_NUMBER`? Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT currencyid, bankid FROM yourtable;` ?

Comment: @JNevill Yes that will return me one row, but I want to delete the other rows. I want them removed out of the table so I need a `DELETE` statement

Comment: The real work is identifying which records you want to keep. So take this result set from `DISTINCT` write it into a temp table or what-have-you, delete all records from your existing table and then blow the records from your temp table into your original table. I think handling this with a single DELETE statement is going to introduce a level of complexity and risk that I, personally, wouldn't be comfortable with in my database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table doesn't have id column, the best option could be using temporaray table:

```
CREATE TABLE bank_currency_temp AS
SELECT DISTINCT bankid, currencyid
FROM bank_currency;
```

After that remove original table

```
DROP TABLE bank_currency
```

Then rename temp table

```
ALTER TABLE bank_currency_temp
RENAME TO bank_currency;
```

Comment: would be better if you included a way to do this in-place so that you don't have to do all sorts of re-setup for the table